# How to get Installation date of an application in C#

Tags: c#

I installed my application on Windows machine. In my C# program, I need to get installed date of this application. Is there a way to get this from registry or some other location. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of that information should be stored in subkeys of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall. You'll have to find the subkey for your particular application.

The information that exists in each subkey depends on the installer used and the installer configuration settings.

Once you've determined that the information you need is there, you can use the `Win32.Registry` and `Win32.RegistryKey` classes to access it.

Comment: Thanks. Howo do I get the key? On my system the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{44FA2BAA-3C54-41D2-9F24-D0EE0131C695}_is1. Is the key hardcoded?

Comment: @codematrix It should always have the same GUID, but you might want to identify it by some other method to avoid mistakes. You can have the installer add a value that you can check for reference later on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The GUID of executing assembly is different from the GUID in the ...\Uninstall\ of registry. Do you know how to get the GUID in the ...\Uninstall\ of registry from C# application?