# Get Install Date in C#.net

Tags: c#, datetime, installation, demo

I Have developed C# windows Application .and I want to create a demo of this application .So I want To get Date of installation of this application to compare with current datetime to check if trial version is expired or not.so how can I get installation date of this application in C#.net

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025444/original-install-date-from-registry

Comment: Installers should create a value in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and should fill out the "InstallDate" key, pretty sure this is the exact value you will see in Control Panel->Programs and Features. @Zath. that answer is to get the Windows install date, not the install date of an application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Installation date of an application in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313264/how-to-get-installation-date-of-an-application-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I tested this code in visual studio .but did not work and retured ' 0001-01-01T00:00:00'

Comment: Storing a value in the registry, or reading out one placed there by Windows Installer, will work in a naive implementation, but it will be easy for a user to circumvent it and use your application indefinitely.

Comment: You could store an xml file that contains the install date locally on the machine when the application installs, obfuscate it some how, then check that xml file every time the application launches.

Comment: xml file can be modify by another user which i donot want this